# Maximal ideal in noetherian local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Given a noetherian domain $A$ of dimension 1, I know that $A/p$ is a noetherian local domain of dimension 1 for any non-zero prime ideal $p$. But what is the maximal ideal of $A/p$?

Comment: What is $p$ ? For an arbitrary ring the maximal ideals of $A/p$ correspond to the maximal ideals of $A$ containing $p$.

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry I forgot to mention that $p$ is a non-zero prime ideal. I have edited the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is wrong. Consider for example the integers, then $\dim(\mathbb{Z})=1$ and it is noetherian as it is a PID but for any prime number we have that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, thus has dimension zero with the only prime ideal $(0)$.
Your problem here is that when factoring out a nonzero prime ideal your dimension reduces, in this case by one as any nonzero prime ideal in a domain of dimension one has height one. So you always end up with a field where the maximal ideal is just $(0)$.